# How do I aggregate by a change-In-state column in a pandas dataframe grouped by datetimes

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, state

Okay, I've been working on this for a while now and I have a solution but it isn't working optimally. Here is an example of what the dataframe looks like:

```
print(month_df[['timestamp','date','hvac_state']].head(100))
             timestamp      date hvac_state
0  2017-11-09 18:43:45  12-09-17        off
1  2017-11-09 20:15:27  12-09-17    heating
2  2017-11-09 22:29:00  12-09-17    heating
3  2017-11-09 23:42:34  12-09-17        off
4  2017-11-10 00:09:40  12-10-17    heating
5  2017-11-10 00:23:14  12-10-17    heating
6  2017-11-10 03:32:17  12-10-17        off
7  2017-11-10 10:59:24  12-10-17    heating
8  2017-11-10 11:12:59  12-10-17        off
9  2017-11-10 13:49:09  12-10-17        off
10 2017-11-10 16:58:11  12-10-17    heating
11 2017-11-10 17:11:45  12-10-17    heating
12 2017-11-10 17:25:19  12-10-17        off
13 2017-11-10 23:53:44  12-10-17        off
14 2017-11-11 00:25:22  12-11-17        off
15 2017-11-11 03:29:53  12-11-17    heating
16 2017-11-11 03:43:26  12-11-17    heating
17 2017-11-11 04:01:31  12-11-17        off
```

There are other fields in the month_df dataframe, but these are the three that I am using. A line gets appended when anything changes. Sometimes the item changing is the hvac_state, sometimes it's a different column. That's why you see that, occasionally, the state doesn't change but there is another entry.

I want to aggregate all the "quantities of time" and state of hvac_state column by day. I found a few articles on groupby and using shift (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21158078/splitting-time-series-data-into-groups-based-on-a-changes-in-state-on-a-column-i)) and that's what I implemented but it isn't perfect because the day cutoffs aren't exactly at 00:00:00-23:59:59 for each day. I can tell this in my aggregate data because I end up with quantities that add up to slightly more than 24 hours. Also, it's obviously not efficient since I'm using a 'timestamp' and a 'date' column to perform this.

This is the the method that I'm currently using:

```
def remove_consecutive_duplicates(a):
    return a.loc[a.shift() != a]

# Get the left data frame ready, with timestamps associated specifically with state changes.
left = remove_consecutive_duplicates(month_df.set_index('timestamp')['hvac_state']).reset_index()
# Then delta from change to change and shift by negative 1.
left['delta'] = left.timestamp.diff().fillna(0).astype(int).shift(-1).fillna(0)
# Now prep the right dataframe by hurling the hvac_state so we don't end up with two.
right = month_df.drop(['hvac_state'], axis=1)
# Perform the merge, dropping the stuff that isn't in the left side.
result = pd.merge(left, right, how='left', on='timestamp')
# Now we can store that month's hourly usage by day.
grouped = (result.groupby(['date','hvac_state'])[['delta']].sum()/3600000).round(2)
results = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))
for index, value in grouped.itertuples():
    for i, key in enumerate(index):
        if i == 0:
            nested = results[key]
        elif i == len(index) - 1:
            nested[key] = value
        else:
            nested = nested[key]

results
defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
            {'12-09-17': defaultdict(dict, {'heating': 3.84, 'off': 10.24}),
             '12-10-17': defaultdict(dict, {'heating': 8.36, 'off': 14.39}),
             '12-11-17': defaultdict(dict, {'heating': 10.17, 'off': 14.91}),
             '12-12-17': defaultdict(dict, {'heating': 9.34, 'off': 13.56}),
             '12-13-17': defaultdict(dict, {'heating': 10.49, 'off': 13.59}),
             '12-14-17': defaultdict(dict, {'heating': 9.58, 'off': 14.72}),
             '12-15-17': defaultdict(dict, {'heating': 6.03, 'off': 24.38}),
             '12-16-17': defaultdict(dict, {'heating': 0.0})})
```

You can see from this example, that on the 15th my "off" time is 24.38 hours, while the "heating" time is 6.03 hours.

I would prefer to get a standard dictionary out (for json use) with the date as the key and the states as the subkeys pointing to the amount of time spent in each state. The state values should add to 24 hours. Ideally, something like this:

```
{
 '12-12-17': {'heating': 5.23, 'off': 18.77},
 '12-13-17': {'heating': 7.85, 'off': 16.15},
 '12-14-17': {'heating': 7.91, 'off': 16.09},
 '12-15-17': {'heating': 6.22, 'off': 17.78},
 '12-16-17': {'heating': 5.11, 'off': 18.89},
 '12-17-17': {'heating': 9.17, 'off': 14.83}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider adding midnight records into your dataframe that is forward filled with last row's HVAC state (except for first record which is back-filled). Below prints out each step of the process:

**Initial data**

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = """             timestamp      date hvac_state
0  "2017-11-09 18:43:45"  "12-09-17"        off
1  "2017-11-09 20:15:27"  "12-09-17"    heating
2  "2017-11-09 22:29:00"  "12-09-17"    heating
3  "2017-11-09 23:42:34"  "12-09-17"        off
4  "2017-11-10 00:09:40"  "12-10-17"    heating
5  "2017-11-10 00:23:14"  "12-10-17"    heating
6  "2017-11-10 03:32:17"  "12-10-17"        off
7  "2017-11-10 10:59:24"  "12-10-17"    heating
8  "2017-11-10 11:12:59"  "12-10-17"        off
9  "2017-11-10 13:49:09"  "12-10-17"        off
10 "2017-11-10 16:58:11"  "12-10-17"    heating
11 "2017-11-10 17:11:45"  "12-10-17"    heating
12 "2017-11-10 17:25:19"  "12-10-17"        off
13 "2017-11-10 23:53:44"  "12-10-17"        off
14 "2017-11-11 00:25:22"  "12-11-17"        off
15 "2017-11-11 03:29:53"  "12-11-17"    heating
16 "2017-11-11 03:43:26"  "12-11-17"    heating
17 "2017-11-11 04:01:31"  "12-11-17"        off"""

month_df = pd.read_table(StringIO(txt), sep="\s+", index_col=0, parse_dates=[0,1])
```

**Midnight Appends**

```
midnights_df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':pd.date_range(month_df['timestamp'].min().normalize(), 
                                                       month_df['timestamp'].max()),
                             'date': pd.date_range(month_df['date'].min(), 
                                                   month_df['date'].max())})
print(midnights_df)
#         date  timestamp
# 0 2017-12-09 2017-11-09
# 1 2017-12-10 2017-11-10
# 2 2017-12-11 2017-11-11

month_df = pd.concat([month_df, midnights_df], ignore_index=True)\
                    .sort_values(['date', 'timestamp'])\
                    .append({'date': month_df['date'].max(),
                             'timestamp': month_df['timestamp'].max().normalize() + 
                             pd.DateOffset(days=1)}, ignore_index=True)\
                    .fillna(method='ffill').reset_index(drop=True)
# BACK FILL
month_df.loc[0, 'hvac_state'] = month_df.loc[1, 'hvac_state']

print(month_df)
#          date hvac_state           timestamp
# 0  2017-12-09        off 2017-11-09 00:00:00
# 1  2017-12-09        off 2017-11-09 18:43:45
# 2  2017-12-09    heating 2017-11-09 20:15:27
# 3  2017-12-09    heating 2017-11-09 22:29:00
# 4  2017-12-09        off 2017-11-09 23:42:34
# 5  2017-12-10        off 2017-11-10 00:00:00
# 6  2017-12-10    heating 2017-11-10 00:09:40
# 7  2017-12-10    heating 2017-11-10 00:23:14
# 8  2017-12-10        off 2017-11-10 03:32:17
# 9  2017-12-10    heating 2017-11-10 10:59:24
# 10 2017-12-10        off 2017-11-10 11:12:59
# 11 2017-12-10        off 2017-11-10 13:49:09
# 12 2017-12-10    heating 2017-11-10 16:58:11
# 13 2017-12-10    heating 2017-11-10 17:11:45
# 14 2017-12-10        off 2017-11-10 17:25:19
# 15 2017-12-10        off 2017-11-10 23:53:44
# 16 2017-12-11        off 2017-11-11 00:00:00
# 17 2017-12-11        off 2017-11-11 00:25:22
# 18 2017-12-11    heating 2017-11-11 03:29:53
# 19 2017-12-11    heating 2017-11-11 03:43:26
# 20 2017-12-11        off 2017-11-11 04:01:31
# 21 2017-12-11        off 2017-11-12 00:00:00
```

**Join Shift Time** *(with time difference calculation)*

From there, considering joining main dataframe with a shifted version that you then run in-line time subtraction for an eventual `groupby` sum.

```
join_df = month_df.join(month_df.shift(-1), lsuffix='', rsuffix='_')
join_df['time_diff'] = (join_df['timestamp_'] - join_df['timestamp']).astype('timedelta64[s]') / 3600.0

print(join_df)
#          date hvac_state           timestamp      date_ hvac_state_          timestamp_  time_diff
# 0  2017-12-09        off 2017-11-09 00:00:00 2017-12-09         off 2017-11-09 18:43:45  18.729167
# 1  2017-12-09        off 2017-11-09 18:43:45 2017-12-09     heating 2017-11-09 20:15:27   1.528333
# 2  2017-12-09    heating 2017-11-09 20:15:27 2017-12-09     heating 2017-11-09 22:29:00   2.225833
# 3  2017-12-09    heating 2017-11-09 22:29:00 2017-12-09         off 2017-11-09 23:42:34   1.226111
# 4  2017-12-09        off 2017-11-09 23:42:34 2017-12-10         off 2017-11-10 00:00:00   0.290556
# 5  2017-12-10        off 2017-11-10 00:00:00 2017-12-10     heating 2017-11-10 00:09:40   0.161111
# 6  2017-12-10    heating 2017-11-10 00:09:40 2017-12-10     heating 2017-11-10 00:23:14   0.226111
# 7  2017-12-10    heating 2017-11-10 00:23:14 2017-12-10         off 2017-11-10 03:32:17   3.150833
# 8  2017-12-10        off 2017-11-10 03:32:17 2017-12-10     heating 2017-11-10 10:59:24   7.451944
# 9  2017-12-10    heating 2017-11-10 10:59:24 2017-12-10         off 2017-11-10 11:12:59   0.226389
# 10 2017-12-10        off 2017-11-10 11:12:59 2017-12-10         off 2017-11-10 13:49:09   2.602778
# 11 2017-12-10        off 2017-11-10 13:49:09 2017-12-10     heating 2017-11-10 16:58:11   3.150556
# 12 2017-12-10    heating 2017-11-10 16:58:11 2017-12-10     heating 2017-11-10 17:11:45   0.226111
# 13 2017-12-10    heating 2017-11-10 17:11:45 2017-12-10         off 2017-11-10 17:25:19   0.226111
# 14 2017-12-10        off 2017-11-10 17:25:19 2017-12-10         off 2017-11-10 23:53:44   6.473611
# 15 2017-12-10        off 2017-11-10 23:53:44 2017-12-11         off 2017-11-11 00:00:00   0.104444
# 16 2017-12-11        off 2017-11-11 00:00:00 2017-12-11         off 2017-11-11 00:25:22   0.422778
# 17 2017-12-11        off 2017-11-11 00:25:22 2017-12-11     heating 2017-11-11 03:29:53   3.075278
# 18 2017-12-11    heating 2017-11-11 03:29:53 2017-12-11     heating 2017-11-11 03:43:26   0.225833
# 19 2017-12-11    heating 2017-11-11 03:43:26 2017-12-11         off 2017-11-11 04:01:31   0.301389
# 20 2017-12-11        off 2017-11-11 04:01:31 2017-12-11         off 2017-11-11 23:59:59  19.974444
# 21 2017-12-11        off 2017-11-12 00:00:00        NaT         NaN                 NaT        NaN
```

**Aggregate** *(by date and hvac_state)*

```
grp_df = join_df.groupby(['date', 'hvac_state']).sum().reset_index()

print(grp_df)
#         date hvac_state  time_diff
# 0 2017-12-09    heating   3.451944
# 1 2017-12-09        off  20.548056
# 2 2017-12-10    heating   4.055556
# 3 2017-12-10        off  19.944444
# 4 2017-12-11    heating   0.527222
# 5 2017-12-11        off  23.472500
```

**Pivot** *(for final needed json)*

```
pvt_df = grp_df.pivot(index='date', columns='hvac_state', values='time_diff')
pvt_df.index = pvt_df.index.astype('str')

print(pvt_df)
# hvac_state   heating        off
# date                           
# 2017-12-09  3.451944  20.548056
# 2017-12-10  4.055556  19.944444
# 2017-12-11  0.527222  23.472500

json_data = pvt_df.to_json(orient='index')

print(json_data)
#  {"2017-12-09":{"heating":3.4519444444,"off":20.5480555556},
#   "2017-12-10":{"heating":4.0555555556,"off":19.9444444444},
#   "2017-12-11":{"heating":0.5272222222,"off":23.4725}
#  }
```

Comment: Thank you @Parfait! That is an excellent explanation and method! I am definitely using it.

Comment: I actually, modified it a bit removing the 'date' column so I only need 'timestamp'. I moved the pd.DateOffset(days=1) to the midnights_df because it was causing issues after fixing the timezone. @Parfait, you are a gentleman and a scholar!

Comment: Haha...StackOverflow, the gift that keeps on giving where the OP learns from a posted solution and extends it to fit actual needs (many posters want an exact plug and chug answer). Glad to help on your interesting question. Happy coding!